# CSS Background Gradient has nast line cut through it.

Tags: html, css

I've got this great website with a full screen gradient background. But it has this nasty line through it **at the end of the cycle.**. What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/jonathansafa/pen/pWjvoO

```
.background{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px; z-index: -1;}
.awesomeBG {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #165730, #185a9d, #165730, #185a9d);
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  animation: AwesomeBG 10s ease infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes AwesomeBG {
  0% { background-position:0 0 }
  5% { background-position:8% 0 }
  13% { background-position:15% 0 }
  19% { background-position:23% 0 }
  25% { background-position:30% 0 }
  31% { background-position:38% 0 }
  38% { background-position:45% 0 }
  44% { background-position:53% 0 }
  50% { background-position:60% 0 }
  56% { background-position:68% 0 }
  63% { background-position:75% 0 }
  69% { background-position:83% 0 }
  75% { background-position:90% 0 }
  81% { background-position:98% 0 }
  88% { background-position:105% 0 }
  94% { background-position:113% 0 }
  100% { background-position:120% 0 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your gradient starts and ends with different colors (starts with `#165730` and ends with `#185a9d`). If you want to get smooth transition without that line, you need to start and to finish your gradient with the same colors. Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7dvovgr7/

And the snippet:

```css
.background{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px; z-index: -1;}
.awesomeBG {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #165730, #185a9d, #165730, #185a9d, #165730);
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  animation: AwesomeBG 10s ease infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes AwesomeBG {
  0% { background-position:0 0 }
  5% { background-position:8% 0 }
  13% { background-position:15% 0 }
  19% { background-position:23% 0 }
  25% { background-position:30% 0 }
  31% { background-position:38% 0 }
  38% { background-position:45% 0 }
  44% { background-position:53% 0 }
  50% { background-position:60% 0 }
  56% { background-position:68% 0 }
  63% { background-position:75% 0 }
  69% { background-position:83% 0 }
  75% { background-position:90% 0 }
  81% { background-position:98% 0 }
  88% { background-position:105% 0 }
  94% { background-position:113% 0 }
  100% { background-position:120% 0 }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background awesomeBG"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong.
It seems you may have just found bug on codepen.

See for yourself.

```css
.background{
  display: flex;
  position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px; z-index: -1;}
.awesomeBG {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #165730, #185a9d, #165730, #185a9d, #165730); /*make sure you start and end with the same color*/
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  animation: AwesomeBG 10s ease infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes AwesomeBG {
  0% { background-position:0 0 }
  5% { background-position:8% 0 }
  13% { background-position:15% 0 }
  19% { background-position:23% 0 }
  25% { background-position:30% 0 }
  31% { background-position:38% 0 }
  38% { background-position:45% 0 }
  44% { background-position:53% 0 }
  50% { background-position:60% 0 }
  56% { background-position:68% 0 }
  63% { background-position:75% 0 }
  69% { background-position:83% 0 }
  75% { background-position:90% 0 }
  81% { background-position:98% 0 }
  88% { background-position:105% 0 }
  94% { background-position:113% 0 }
  100% { background-position:120% 0 }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background awesomeBG"></div>
</body>
```